# How can I know if I can keep my 8gb memory units when upgrading from E8400 to Core i7 930

Tags: upgrade, memory

Ideally without opening my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and Install [CPUID](http://www.cpuid.com).  It will tell you what type of memory is currently installed in the system.  Compare it with the fact sheet on the new motherboard to see if it is compatible.

The other option is to pull up the specs for both motherboards and compare the memory types.